# parsing the result of web api

Tags: api, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am new in web api. I have called a external web api

```
 var url = "http://service.mydomain.com/api/GetItems";

 var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 parameters["id"] = "10";
 using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
 {
     var post = client.PostAsync(url, new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters)).Result;
     if (post.IsSuccessStatusCode)
     {                   
        var result = post.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();                    
     }
 }
```

the result value is

```
"{\"Status\":1,\"Data\":{\"state\":1,\"message\":\"Done Successfully\",\"WorkName\":\"test\",\"WorkUrl\":\"192.168.1.10/go\"},\"Message\":null}"
```

how can I access any items of the result value

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class that matches the expected layout of the json response and then deserialize into that.

```
public class MyModelData
{
    public int State { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string WorkName { get; set; }
    public string WorkUrl { get; set; }
}
public class MyModel
{
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public MyModelData Data { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Then use:

```
string result = post.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
MyModel model = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyModel>(result);
```

or

```
MyModel model = post.Content.ReadAsJsonAsync();
```